# MySql Reblog/Retweet

Tags: mysql

I've incorporated a reblog system in an app I'm building but am having a hard time figuring out the logic to retrieve the posts **and** the reblogs in the same stream.

I have a `post_reblog` pivot table to store the `post_id` and the `user_id` - the ID of the user who reblogged the post.

The following query retrieves the posts, but *not* the reblogged post - only the original. I can't figure out how to retrieve **both** the original post **and** the reblogged post and share them in the same stream.

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
Where status = 'published'
OR id IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT post_id FROM post_reblog ) AS subquery)
```

My tables

```
posts
    post_id (int)
    user_id (int)
    title   (varchar)
    body    (text)

post_reblog
    post_id (int)
    user_id (int)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that all the reblogged posts are in the query. When you use an `OR` like that, each row is only able to appear once.
One possible solution is a union:

```
SELECT post_id, user_id 'original poster', user_id 'current poster', title, body
FROM posts
WHERE status = 'published'
UNION ALL
SELECT p.post_id, p.user_id 'original poster', pr.user_id 'current poster', p.title, p.body
FROM post_reblog pr
INNER JOIN posts p ON p.post_id = pr.post_id
WHERE p.status = 'published'
```

Note, it is a `UNION ALL`, as `UNION ALL` does not remove duplicate rows.
Also, note that the difference in the two queries is that 'current poster' is the republisher.